# How to do manual reindexing in Magento EE 1.13?

Tags: php, magento

Last two days i want to reindex Url Redirects index in Magento EE 1.13 from admin panel but  cannot . Only two indexes "Product Attributes" and "Tag Aggregation Data" are showing with checkboxes rest donot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working and googling i found that it is default functionality since Magento EE 1.13 . They have allowed just two indexes that can be done manually. Rest can be done by scheduling or on save. If we still need to do reindexing there is no way to do it from Magento admin and we have to use the shell(ssh) way.

Answer (score 1):

You can reindex via shell (ssh).
Reindexing Url Redirects index, add command:

`php ./shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_url`

on your magento root.

For more info and other commands, see: http://www.magentotutorials.co.uk/reindex-data-via-ssh

Comment: I need the ability to index from magento admin. I know we can index from shell.

Answer (score 0):

I think wrong permission is set in "var/locks" folder. open it and see modification date of files.

If proper permission are set (755), remove those files and try to re run indexing.

:)

Comment: Hey pal. All I did was give you a link that answered your question. That's no reason to go around down voting my answers. And yes, I've already verified that it was you.

Comment: Actuall since magento EE 1.13  the indexing has been made automated and just two indexes allowed to index from Magento admin. So its the default functionality of Magento EE 1.13 onwards.